# Cleaning html code from another website using php

Tags: php, parsing, dom, simplexml, simple-html-dom

I want to get some data from [this](https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics&world=Menera) website but as you can see in their html code there are some weird stuff going on as `<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=1 CELLPADDING=3 WIDTH=100%>` without using "" and some other stuff, so I'm having errors when I try to parse the table using SimpleXmlElement which I have been using for a few time and works perfectly in some websites,
I'm doing something like:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics&world=Menera');
$table = $html->find('table', 4);

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($table);
```

I get a bunch of erros and stuff, so is there a way of cleaning the code before sending to SimpleXmlElement or perhaps using another kind of DOM class?
What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your HTML code is that the tag attributes are not wrapped by quotes: unquoted attributes are allowed in HTML, but not in XML.

If you don't care about attributes, you can continue using Simple HTML Dom, otherwise you have to change HTML parser.

#### Cleaning attributes with Simple HTML DOM:

Start creating a function to clear all node attributes:

```
function clearAttributes( $node )
{
    foreach( $node->getAllAttributes() as $key => $val )
    {
        $node->$key = Null;
    }
}
```

Then apply the function to your `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` nodes:

```
clearAttributes( $table );

foreach( $table->find('tr') as $tr )
{
    clearAttributes( $tr );

    foreach( $tr->find( 'td' ) as $td )
    {
        clearAttributes( $td );
    }

}
```

Last but not least: site HTML contains a lot of encoded characters. If you don't want see a lot of `<td>1&#xA0;</td><td>0&#xA0;</td>` inside your XML, you have to prepend at your string a `utf-8` declaration before importing it in a `SimpleXml` object:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'.html_entity_decode( $table );
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement( $xml );
```

#### Preserving attributes with DOMDocument:

The built-in `DOMDocument` class is more powerful and less memory hungry than `Simple HTML Dom`. In this case, it will well-format original HTML for you. Despite appearances, its use is simple.

First, you have to init a `DOMDocument` object, setting `libxml_use_internal_errors` (to suppress a lot of warnings on malformed HTML) and load your url:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors( 1 );
$dom->loadHTMLfile( 'https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics&world=Menera' );
$dom->formatOutput = True;
```

Then, you retrieve desired `<table>`:

```
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'table' )->item(4);
```

And, like in `Simple HTML Dom` example, you have to prepend `utf-8` declaration to avoid *weird* characters:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$dom->saveHTML( $table );
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement( $xml );
```

As you can see, the `DOMDocument` syntax to retrieve a node as HTML is different than `Simple HTML Dom`: you need always to refer to main object and specify the node to print as argument:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();          // print entire HTML document
echo $dom->saveHTML( $node );   // print node $node
```

#### Edit: removing &nbsp; with DOMDocument:

To remove unwanted `&#160;` from HTML, you can pre-load HTML and use `str_replace`.

Change this line:

```
$dom->loadHTMLfile( 'https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics&world=Menera' );
```

with this:

```
$data = file_get_contents( 'https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics&world=Menera' );
$data = str_replace( '&#160;', '', $data );
$dom->loadHTML( $data );
```

Comment: great code bud, sure helped a lot, but I have a little problem now, when I try to intersect values between arrays `array_intersect($creatureNames,$result)`  the result will be empty, and after some hours I figured it out why, when I do a var_dump on the result coming from the table it returns let's say 'Achad' it will return  `[1]=> string(7) "Achad "` , it should be 5 right? when I checked the table on the website I noticed there was `<TD>Achad&#160;</TD>` the 160 thing is probably adding 2 characters to the string, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What solution you use? simplehtmldom or domdocument?

Comment: I've used your domdocument, I'm trying `str_replace` but nothing seems to work

Comment: @Jambo answer edited. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sweet! it worked! Also       `$name = $tr->td[0];
  $nbsp = html_entity_decode("&nbsp;");
  $name = str_replace($nbsp,"",$name);` worked, thanks again bud